# Unexpected return of a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, nextjs

I have a function on my contract that return true if the address on one list is equal to the msg.sender. The function works fine on remix but when I call it utilizing javascript with next.js and web3.js it is returning false. What could it be?

Comment: Quite obviously the `msg.sender` is some other address.

Comment: Sure, but why? The address at zero is the address that should be calling the function and its the same that is added to the list of addresses...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem was that when i set the web3 provider by default it calls the function of the contract with the first account connected to the dapp, so i need to specify the account that i want to use when passing the .call() method on the web3js! Tks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msg.sender does not same in your test code and you logic, you have to send your transaction from msg.sender in your test. For example in web3.js you can use "from:msg.sender" for sending transaction with specify address .sample code is:

```
let transaction = await yourContract.yourFunction(ag1, arg2,....(other input arguments), { from: msg.sender});
```

you must use the same msg.sender with an address initiated in the contract.

Comment: But what if my function in the contract is the type view? In the web3.js the method call() has a from property?

Comment: for view function you can see this question:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60117/calling-a-view-function-using-web3js
and for call() property goes here:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/web3-eth.html?highlight=call()#call

Comment: That was it! Tks!
i solved the problem simply by adding the .call({from: address[0]}). Reading the documentation and with your help i learned that by default the web3.js call() method set the msg.sender to the first account on the wallet, so especifing the account index in the call method make it work!